What gives the gel like substance in tomato its flavour, how to utilise it when cooking?
I’ve noticed there’s a particular taste to tomatoes which I’m really liking at the moment.
I could be wrong but Having investigated I think the part I’m liking is the gel which is in the Center of the tomato and it’s also on the surface of the seeds.  It maybe throughout the whole tomato but it’s in the gel I notice the taste the most.
What is this gel like substance called and what gives its taste?  I read that a lot of glutamic acid is concentrated here so would that be the thing that gives this taste or something else?
If I wanted to make a particular dish taste very strongly like this, what cooking method would it work best with such as stew, soup, frying etc.
Would a water(stew/soup) just dilute the gel so reduce the taste or would it make the water taste like it so water is a good carrier?  I fried some tomatoes in a bit of tallow but I couldn’t taste the gel throughout the meal. this could be because the gel got destroyed in the frying process, the gel is stuck to the pan etc?  I only used two teaspoons of fat and can’t really see the fat anymore so perhaps there’s no liquid or fat to carry the gel taste over and maybe I need to add more fat next time if that helps?
Just to add, I could be wrong but it seems cooking may bring out this taste more.
Thanks.

https://www.foodandwine.com/cooking-techniques/how-make-tomato-water-and-what-do-it

Jose Andres, world renown chef and humanitarian, wrote in one of his early tapas cookbooks that he and his colleagues made the same discovery when working with tomatoes at El Bulli early in his career.  In that cookbook, if I remember correctly, he makes a tapa with the seed/gel part of the tomato and watermelon.  I don't think there is a way to re-create it, you just have to find a perfectly ripe tomato, cut away the flesh, and use the interior. Andres' application was a raw dish. I think cooking would negatively impact the experience.  I see that @Sneftel linked a technique for making tomato water. That is delicious as well, and would give you an excellent tomato flavor, but it is not the same because you would not have the mouthfeel of the interior of the tomato, which I think adds to the impact.

This is a great answer. A link to the recipe for the interested: https://joseandres.com/recipes/tomato-watermelon-skewers/

@BenjaminKuykendall thanks for finding and linking!

The gel is rarely used in cooking. Cooks either use the whole tomato, or they throw out the seeds and gel and use only the fleshy part. So it doesn't receive much attention.

What is this gel like substance called

There is no culinary name for it. Botanists call it "locular gel", but that won't help you find resources on cooking with it.

and what gives its taste?

Everything? Your sense of taste works by trying to uniquely label the whole combination of stimuli reaching your nervous system. Of course there are thousands of substances in the tomato gel, each with its own taste, but it's the combination that gives it the taste of tomato gel. Your question is like looking at a photograph of Julia Child and asking which pixel makes the photograph look like her - no pixel on its own does it.
Glutamic acid is present in the whole tomato, so it's unlikely that it is the reason why you prefer the gel over other parts of the tomato.

If I wanted to make a particular dish taste very strongly like this, what cooking method would it work best

None.
Making "a particular dish taste very strongly like [an ingredient]" basically works in two ways. The easy one is to make your ingredient the bulk of the dish, do minimal changes to it, and don't include much other ingredients. For example, mashed potatoes taste like potatoes, because they consist of almost nothing but potatoes. Given that you like the taste of raw tomato gel, the only way here would be to make a salad of but uncooked tomato seeds with some minimal additions - which is impractical, not a soup or stew, and likely not what you had in mind.
The other way is restricted to very few ingredients, which happen to have very concentrated flavor. We call such natural occurring ingredients "spices", and there are only a few plants which can be used that way. Tomato seed gel isn't one of them. It's actually especially unsuited for the task, since it doesn't contain any strong aromatics, and it's mostly water. You probably won't even get any mileage out of trying to partially dehydrate it (which can be a strategy when creating fruit flavors in patisserie) because it's so mild in flavor, because so much of the sensory stimulation you get from it is through the texture, and also because you'll be left with almost nothing after dehydration.
Conclusion: if you enjoy tomato seed gel, eat it as it is. It's not an ingredient which can be used to change the flavor of other food.
